# In Javascript, given key/value pairs, return values from array of keys

Tags: javascript

```
const pairs = { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3 }
const keyArray = [a, b, c]
```

I'm trying to get a function or w/e that returns [1, 2, 3]. can't think of anything please help

Comment: Is it JavaScript?

Comment: yeah this is javascript

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to find the values in `pairs` that have keys specified in `keyArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const pairs = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3 }
const keyArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for(const item of keyArray)
{
    console.log(pairs[item])
}
```

You need to make your items inside the array and object as strings

Comment: thanks for the help. it actually worked i was stuck on it for a while

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Happy Coding 

Answer (score 1):

In javascript all keys of an object are actually strings, and can be addressed using the same strings.

Your code is creating an array containing the values of the - possibly uninitialized - variables `a`, `b` and `c`, which then produces `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, or else whatever those variables contain.

You need to make `keyArray` contain **strings** instead, and then you can use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to produce the desired result:

```js
const pairs = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c": 3 }
const keyArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
const values = keyArray.map(key => pairs[key]);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: For my money, this is the better/best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's Javascript

Object.values() should do it.

```
const keyArray = Object.values(pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const pairs = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3 }

for(const [key , value] of Object.entries(pairs))
{
    console.log(key) // a , b, c
    console.log(value) // 1, 2, 3
}
```